# join with AND id=1 with SQL::Abstract::More

Tags: sql, perl

I'm trying to do a join using [SQL::Abstract::More](https://metacpan.org/) that has an `and and then a literal value, not on a table column.

```
=>{table.table_id=table_id,table_log.date>table.date,table_log.event_id=1}
            gd_audit_log
```

the resulting output that I want

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_log ON ( 
    table_log.date > table.date
    AND table.table_id = table_log.table_id
    AND table_log.event_id = 1
)
```

this code works except for

```
AND table_log.event_id = 1
```

the error is

```
... failed: Unknown column 'table_log.1' in 'on clause'
```

obviously it's generating the wrong SQL, what I'm trying to figure out is how to get it to generate the SQL I need.

Comment: MySQL uses `=`, not `==`.

Comment: I know... this question is about how to get SQLA::More to generate the correct SQL. I know what the result needs to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [RT Bug 84972](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=84972). To insert a literal value, you need to use the hashref syntax, instead 
of the string syntax :

```
my $result = $sqla->join(
 'table',
 { operator => '=>',
   condition => { '%1$s.table_id' => {-ident => '%2$s.table_id'},
                  '%2$s.date'     => {'>' => {-ident => '%1$s.date'}},
                  '%2$s.event_id' => 1}},
 'table_log'
);
```

Comment: Could you copy that answer into this one?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that `table_log.event_id = 1` isn't a valid `join` clause, but should be in a `where` clause.

Comment: putting in in the where clause would have the same effect except that it would promote the left join to an inner join

Answer (score 0):

Use force Luke

```
qw/table
=>{table.table_id=table_id,table_log.date>table.date,table_log.event_id='1'}
table_log/
```

need 'escape' 1 by single quote